# Deploying Model with Azure ML Environments

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have been able to successfully host a model using the image config method

```
service = Webservice.deploy_from_model(workspace=ws,
                                   name='name_of_model',
                                   deployment_config=aciconfig,
                                   models=[model],
                                   image_config=image_config)
```

However this method is to be deprecated with the Environment Method

Hence I attempted using the Environment method suggested below in the deprecation message. But I always get a timeout . It never deploys successfully like the old container method

[How to Use Environments - Microsoft Azure ML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments)

My Environment based deployment code

My code is below with the inference_config pointing out to the score.py and deployment_config pointing to the specs of the container. I can see that the service gets created and the model being uploaded . But the service never goes to "Healthy" state. However the same code in the container deployment model works fine .

```
service = Model.deploy(
workspace = ws,
name = "name_of_model",
models = [model],
inference_config = inference_config,
deployment_config = deployment_config)
```

My env configuration from an existing environment provided by Azure ML

```
my_env=Environment.get(workspace=ws,name='AzureML-Scikit-learn-0.20.3') # using Azure Optimized sklearn environment
```

This env being referenced in the inference config

```
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script="scorev3.py", environment=my_env) # using the initialized variable my_env
```

Any clue as to why I'm having a time-out when deploying this ?. I certainly feel its not to do with the internet connection as the old method takes similar long time (10-12  minutes) to deploy and goes through perfect ?